# C# Store two dependent vectors

Tags: c#, .net

Having a same length `time` and `data` value. Both are `double`. 
What's the best method to save this values?

```
List<Tuple<double, double>>
Tuple<List<double>, List<double>>
```

Or anything completely different?

Comment: What are your needs? what are you going to do with them?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad questions + an affirmation, "they are different things"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would make a class and have a `List` of items of that class.

```
class TimeData
{
  double time;
  double data;
}

List<TimeData> values;
```

You could look into making it a struct but classes are easier to handle in C#

Comment: Structs will require less memory overall, remove one level of indirection from accesses, and require less strain on the GC.  However, they will be two to four times the size of an object reference (depending on architecture) and therefore take slightly longer to copy.  I would suggest that the OP benchmark both under real-world conditions if performance is a concern.

Comment: +1. A new type is the way to go. The general rule of thumb is to just use classes. With structs you have to adhere to fairly strict guidelines to see any performance benefit, and they may end up negatively impacting performance. MSDN has a short article on this: [Choosing Between Classes and Structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx).